# Diameter of a bounded closed set

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

For a metric space $(X, d)$, if $M \subset X$ is compact, then $\exists x_0, y_0 \in M: \mathrm{diam}(M) = d(x_0, y_0)$.

I can prove it by $\mathrm{diam}(M) - 1/n < d(x_n, y_n) \le \mathrm{diam}(M)$. And since $M$ is compact, there is $x_{n_k} \to x_0 \in M$ and $y_{n_{k_l}} \to y_0 \in M$.

Is there any example to show that this does **NOT** hold for bounded closed set? I know I should check in $\mathrm{dim}X = \infty$ (otherwise compact is equivalent to bounded closed), but I can not find a counterexample yet.

Comment: In a metric space, compacntess implies closed and bounded. For the reverse, I think you need your space to be complete.

Comment: The rational numbers are a metric space in which you might be able to find a counterexample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $X=\mathbb{Q}$ with the induced metric from $\mathbb{R}$. Then $F=[-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}]\cap \mathbb{Q}$ is a closed bounded subset of $X$, but for every $x,y\in F$, $|x-y|<2\sqrt{2}=\text{diam }F$.

Comment: Bounded closed is different from compact iff $\mathrm{dim}X = \infty$. So does it imply that $\mathrm{dim}\mathbb{Q} = \infty$?

Comment: That result is true for normed vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. I'm considering a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I can understand that (1). $\mathbb{Q}$ is a linear space over field $\mathbb{Q}$ (while it is not a linear space over $\mathbb{R}$, right?), (2). $F$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ (while not a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$, right?). But I still can't understand why $\mathbb{Q}$ is a infinity dimensional space.

Comment: It isn't infinite-dimensional! It has dimension $1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. If you look at the proof of that theorem (bounded closed not compact iff $\dim X = \infty$), you use the completeness of the base field (which we don't have here).

Comment: The small-inductive-dimension $ind(\Bbb Q)$ is $0. $

Comment: You gave a nice simple example..... For an example with a complete metric $d,$ let $X=\Bbb R\cup $ with $d(x,y)=\frac {|x-y|}{1+|x-y|}.$  Then the diameter of $X$ is $1$  but $ d(x.y)<1$ for all $x,y\in X.$

Comment: @ViníciusNovelli yes that's exactly why I'm confused. I ignored the completeness of the base field and struggled to find an example in infinity dimensional space